# jQuery Multiple start and end Dates based on User Input

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I'm working with some older code and am looking to see if there is a way to have the users enter in a number into the a text box and when the create button is clicked it will generate the given number of  start and end dates. the following code works for the most part but the newly created date fields wont populate with the calendar. I feel that this is because the page has already been loaded and I'm just appending text to the end of the already loading page. Is there a work around for this and is there away to identify what dates belong to which block of code when submitted?

Ill update as needed.

from what I can see the code base is using jQuery v1.8 and [jQuery-ui](https://api.jqueryui.com/1.8/datepicker/) v1.8 so they are pretty old.

Example would be if I entered in the number 2 I would get two of the following code generated twice.

**HTML**

```
       <tr>
        <td class="DisplayFieldName">
            # of dates
        </td>
        <td class="DisplayFieldData" style="padding: 0px 0px 0px 5px;">
            <input type="text" name="numOfDates" id="numOfDates" value="0" />
            <button class="numOfDatesBtn" id="numOfDatesBtn" type="button">Add Dates</button>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th style="color:Black;background-color:#D1D1D1;padding:5px;" align="right">
            <label>Period</label>
        </th>
        <th style="color:Black;background-color:#D1D1D1;padding:5px;">
            <label>Start</label>
        </th>
        <th style="color:Black;background-color:#D1D1D1;padding:5px;"></th>
        <th style="color:Black;background-color:#D1D1D1;padding:5px;">
            <label>End</label>
        </th>
        <th style="color:Black;background-color:#D1D1D1;padding:5px;"></th>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td>User 1: </td>
        <td>@Html.CheckBox("User1", true)</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>user 2: </td>
        <td>@Html.CheckBox("User2", true)</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><label for="startDate">Start:</label></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="startDate" value="" id="newStartDate" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><label for="startDate">Buy It Not:</label></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="buyitnow" value="" id="buyItNowDate" /></td>

        <td><input type="text" name="butitnow" value="" id="buyItNowEndDate" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><label for="endDate">End:</label></td>
        <td></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="endDate" value="" id="newEndDate" /></td>
    </tr>
```

**JavaScrpt/jQuery**

```
$('#newStartDate').datetimepicker({ dateFormat: "m/dd/yy", timeFormat: "h:mmtt" });
$('#buyItNowDate').datetimepicker({ dateFormat: "m/dd/yy", timeFormat: "h:mmtt" });
$('#buyItNowEndDate').datetimepicker({ dateFormat: "m/dd/yy", timeFormat: "h:mmtt" });
$('#newEndDate').datetimepicker({ dateFormat: "m/dd/yy", timeFormat: "h:mmtt" });

$("#numOfDatesBtn").click(function () {
    var num = parseInt($("#numOfDates").val());

    for (var i = 1; i <= num; i++)
    {                             
        $(wrapper).append(fieldHTML3); //Add field html            
    }

});

var fieldHTML3 = '<tr>'+
                    '<td><label for="startDate">Start:</label></td>'+
                    '<td><input type="text" name="startDate" value="" id="newStartDate" /></td>'+
                '</tr>'+
                '<tr>'+
                    '<td><label for="startDate">Buy It Not:</label></td>'+
                    '<td><input type="text" name="buyitnow" value="" id="buyItNowDate" /></td>'+

                    '<td><input type="text" name="butitnow" value="" id="buyItNowEndDate" /></td>'+
                '</tr>'+
                '<tr>'+
                    '<td><label for="endDate">End:</label></td>'+
                    '<td></td>'+
                    '<td><input type="text" name="endDate" value="" id="newEndDate" /></td>'+
                '</tr>'
```

Comment: Your example does not provide a complete example. Please provide a Minimal, Reproducible Example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: The issue is related to the elements not existing when you initialize DateTimePicker. You may need to do a refresh or initialize the new elements. Also this code will generate new elements with the same ID. This is an issue in HTML Syntax as ID must be unique.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the following example.

```
$(function() {
  function initDateTime(tObj) {
    tObj.datetimepicker({
      dateFormat: "m/dd/yy",
      timeFormat: "h:mmtt"
    });
  }

  function makenewDateTimePicker(i, tObj) {
    var startRow = $("<tr>").appendTo(tObj);
    var startLabel = $("<td>").html("<label for='start-date-" + i + "'>Start:</label>").appendTo(startRow);
    var startInput = $("<td>").html("<input type='text' id='start-date-" + i + "' />").appendTo(startRow);
    initDateTime($('#start-date-' + i));

    var endRow = $("<tr>").appendTo(tObj);
    var endLabel = $("<td>").html("<label for='end-date-" + i + "'>Start:</label>").appendTo(startRow);
    var endInput = $("<td>").html("<input type='text' id='end-date-" + i + "' />").appendTo(startRow);
    initDateTime($('#end-date-' + i));
  }

  $("#numOfDatesBtn").click(function() {
    var num = parseInt($("#numOfDates").val());
    var c = $("input[id^='start-date']").length;
    c++;
    for (c; c <= num; c++) {
      makenewDateTimePicker(c, $("table"));
    }
  });
});
```

As we initialize each of the DateTimePickers with the same settings, we can make a quick function to do that, where we pass in a jQuery Object.

We can use this same function inside another function when we want to make new Rows and Cells in the table for both the Start and End pickers. Since we're iterating over a set number of loops, we first want to see if there are any existing elements so we can create unique IDs.

Comment: Thank you @Twisty for the reply, could you explain the `initDateTime` function? From what I'm seeing when ever its called its adding a `datatimepicker` obj.. but where does this obj get stored or displayed?

Comment: @whisk the function accepts a jQuery Object. So for example, `initDateTime($('#start-date-1'));`, this object would need to exist in the HTML.

Comment: I guess I'm wondering more about the  `tObj.datetimepicker` part of it. I got your code to work but the only problem I'm having is getting the `datetimepicker` showing up when I click the `input` box.

Comment: @whisk are you seeing any errors in console? Can you make a basic test to ensure that DateTimePicker is working properly normally? Otherwise please provide an update to your question and include a Complete Example.

Comment: OK so there wasn't any errors in the console, but digging deeper I found a line of code `$.datepicker.setDefaults({ showOn: "button", ...});` setting it so you have to have a button to show it. commented it out and everything worked.